# how to disable discovery/visibility of HC-05 bluetooth module

Tags: module, arduino, bluetooth, visibility, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am using hc-05 module interfaced with an arduino to connect with android device.

**What i am trying now is to disable hc-05 bluetooth module discovery/visibility to other device.**
In short i want to make hc-05 module invisible to other devices.

My Setup:

- bluetooth module is in slave mode
- i am using insecure rfcomm to communicate with bluetooth module.

what i have tried so far.

- tried to set inquiry Interval to 0 by using AT+IPSCAN command as mentioned [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=214821.0)

Comment: I have the same issue. Please help.